# Excel formula to count date ranges

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I need to come up with a formula that will count the number of rows of a date column. I need greater than 365, 300-365, 299-230 ect all the way down to 30 days. One formula for each will be perfect and as long as I can figure out the first couple, I can get the rest. Help is much appreciated.

The date format in the excel table is: 9/1/2021

A year or older. Seems this may be close but it's giving an error

`=COUNTIF(A1:A1000,">="=DATE(YEAR(=TODAY()-1)))`

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A1000,">="=DATE(DAY(=TODAY()-364)),A1:A1000,"<="=DATE(DAY(=TODAY()-300)))`

Comment: Remove the "=" signs from inside your formulae (outside the quotes).

Comment: OK sure but that still doesn't make it work

```=COUNTIF(A1:A1000,">="DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-1)))```

Comment: You are missing & too - see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than 365 days ago:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A1000,"<="&TODAY()-365)`

300-365 days ago (need countifs in order to do multiple criteria)

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A1000,">="&TODAY()-365,A1:A1000,"<="&TODAY()-300)`

Comment: The second one is only returning a date. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Think about using [Frequency](https://exceljet.net/formula/histogram-with-frequency) - this works in most versions of Excel, but has to be array-entered in non-365:

```
=FREQUENCY(A2:A1000,TODAY()-C2:C11)
```

The bin values can be entered into the sheet as below or expressed as an array constant in curly brackets. Note that each bin includes values *less than or equal to* the corresponding cut-point, so the first value is 366:

[image]

If all bin sizes were equal, you could use Sequence in Excel 365 to generate the bin ranges.